# regex to put an actual newline at every \n

Tags: mysql, regex, bash-scripting

I'm writing a bash script that will deal with blob data that needs to be written to a file. The data inserted into the blob is separated by newlines. The command line `mysql -e select blobfield from datatable > file.txt` returns data of the form `foo\nbar\nbaz\nmoo`.
I would like to write it out to a file that looks like

`foo

bar

baz

moo`

This obviously looks like a regex job, but how do I replace \n with \n?

Comment: won't this go to StackOverflow.com?

Comment: I don't know. Shell scripts, especially small ones like this, are a fine line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below -

```
sed  's/\\n/\n/g' file.txt > blob.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but it goes to stdout, not blob.txt. Why not?

Comment: sorry...misunderstood question...see update.